# How to find concurrent number of connections per second with Apache?

Tags: apache-httpd, performance, load, concurrency

A web-server hosting an application for a client ; which is high-volume or transaction server, it is required to find out "number of concurrent connections" currently in use by the server. This is required for a solution e.g NGFW, or WAF that is based upon this metric.

Can I run some script or builtin plugin to find this number? I need solution for Apache.

Comment: Do you mean the number of currently established TCP connections on port 80?

Comment: Its ssl and its just not connections but number of HTTPs request per second

Comment: Then please edit your question, that's a  completely different requirement. Do you want to know how many HTTP requests have been received, processed, answered in the past second? Or are currently being processed? Or on average per second since the  last time you checked?

Comment: For a start, see http://localhost/server-status if mod_status has been enabled.

Comment: How about checking the access log with something like grep "$(date -d -1secs)" access_log | wc -l